# Hi I have developed weather app but when I am not able to get weather icons?

Tags: java, android

***I am developing weather android app where I want to show weather condition with the corresponding description as an icon but image view not showing Url icon
              Below my Ending points***

```
        public interface ApiService {
        @GET("/v1/search.json?")
            // return type is List
        Call<List<Weather>> getWeather(
                @Query("key") String mKey,
                @Query("q") String mCityName);
        @GET("v1/forecast.json")
        Call<ForecastEndingPoint> forecast(
                @Query("key") String key,
                @Query("q") String condition,
                @Query("days") int days
        );


    }
```

**Below my WeatherClient.java class where I have declared API URL**

```
        public class WeatherClient {
            private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://api.apixu.com";

            /**
             * Get Retrofit Instance
             */
            private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
                return new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }

            /**
             * Get API Service
             *
             * @return API Service
             */
            public static ApiService getApiService() {
                return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
            }
        }
```

**below my ConditionAdapter.java class where I have implemented weather description and icon**

```
    public class ConditionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConditionAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

        public List<ForecastEndingPoint> forecastList;
        public Context context;
        public  Context picassoContext;
        private final int  imageWidthPixels = 1024;
        private final int imageHeightPixels = 768;
        public ConditionAdapter(List<ForecastEndingPoint> forecastList, Context context, Context picassoContext) {
            this.forecastList = forecastList;
            this.context = context;
            this.picassoContext = picassoContext;

        }


        @Override
        public ConditionAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.weather_list, parent, false);

            return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //        String icon = condition1.getCurrent().getCondition().getIcon();

            //      int r = map.get(icon);


            ForecastEndingPoint forecastEndingPoint = forecastList.get(position);
            holder.weatherDescription.setText((String.valueOf(forecastEndingPoint.getCurrent().getCondition().getText())));
          //  Condition condition =  new Condition();
            Picasso.get().load(forecastEndingPoint.getCurrent().getCondition().getIcon())
                    .fit().centerCrop().into(holder.weatherIcon);

          //  @@ -80,7 +80,7 @@ public int getItemCount() {
           // Picasso.get().load(forecastEndingPoint.getCurrent().getCondition().getIcon((holder.weatherIcon)));
            // holder.weatherCode.setText(condition2.getCode());

            //   Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, r);
            //  holder.weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);

            //  Picasso.get(getApplication).load((forecastEndingPoint.getCurrent().getCondition().getIcon(holder.weatherIcon)));
            //holder.weatherCode.setText(icon);

            //holder.weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            //holder.weatherDescription.setText(condition.getText());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return forecastList.size();
        }

        public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView  weatherDescription;
            public ImageView weatherIcon;


            public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                weatherDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.weatherDescription);

                //  weatherDescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.weatherDescription);
                weatherIcon =  view.findViewById(R.id.weatherIcon);

            }
        }
    }
```

**below my WeatherAdapter class where I have implemented city name and region**

```
    public class WeatherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

        private List<Weather> weathers;
        private List<Condition> conditionList;
        private Context context;

        public WeatherAdapter(List<Weather> weathers) {
            this.weathers = weathers;

        }





        @Override
        public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.weather_list, parent, false);

            return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {



            Weather weather = weathers.get(position);
            holder.andijanView.setText(weather.getName());



            holder.regionView.setText(weather.getRegion());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return weathers.size();
        }

        public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView andijanView, regionView;


            public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                andijanView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.andijanView);
                regionView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.regionView);


            }
        }
    }

    below my weather_list.xml class
    public class WeatherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

        private List<Weather> weathers;
        private List<Condition> conditionList;
        private Context context;

        public WeatherAdapter(List<Weather> weathers) {
            this.weathers = weathers;

        }





        @Override
        public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.weather_list, parent, false);

            return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {



            Weather weather = weathers.get(position);
            holder.andijanView.setText(weather.getName());



            holder.regionView.setText(weather.getRegion());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return weathers.size();
        }

        public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView andijanView, regionView;


            public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                andijanView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.andijanView);
                regionView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.regionView);


            }
        }
    }
```

**and activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**below my MainActivity.java class where I am getting weather response**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private List<Weather> weatherArrayList;
        private List<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionList;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private WeatherAdapter adapter;
        private ConditionAdapter conditionAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data.. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            //Creating an object of our api interface
            ApiService api = WeatherClient.getApiService();

            /**
             * Calling JSON
             */
            Call<List<Weather>> call = api.getWeather("6bed69052a864d44a8e165653183008", "Andijan");
            Call<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionCall = api.forecast("6bed69052a864d44a8e165653183008", "Andijan", 10);

            /**
             * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
             */
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Weather>>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Weather>> call, Response<List<Weather>> response) {
                    //Dismiss Dialog
                    //    Log.d("url", call.request().url().toString());
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        /**
                         * Got Successfully
                         */
                        weatherArrayList = response.body();

                        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

                        LinearLayoutManager eLayoutManager = null;

                        adapter = new WeatherAdapter((List<Weather>) weatherArrayList);
                        eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Weather>> call, Throwable t) {
                    //  Log.d("error", "" + t.getMessage());
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            conditionCall.enqueue(new Callback<ForecastEndingPoint>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionCall, Response<ForecastEndingPoint> response) {
                    //Dismiss Dialog
                    //    Log.d("url", call.request().url().toString());
                    if (pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        /**
                         * Got Successfully
                         */
                        conditionList = Collections.singletonList(response.body());

                        recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

                        LinearLayoutManager eLayoutManager = null;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        Context picassoContext = getApplicationContext();
                        conditionAdapter = new ConditionAdapter( conditionList, context,picassoContext );
                        eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(conditionAdapter);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ForecastEndingPoint> conditionCall, Throwable t) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**below response for weather condition**

```
{
        "location": {
            "name": "Andijan",
            "region": "Andijon",
            "country": "Uzbekistan",
            "lat": 40.78,
            "lon": 72.34,
            "tz_id": "Asia/Tashkent",
            "localtime_epoch": 1535973113,
            "localtime": "2018-09-03 16:11"
        },
        "current": {
            "last_updated_epoch": 1535972213,
            "last_updated": "2018-09-03 15:56",
            "temp_c": 30.5,
            "temp_f": 86.9,
            "is_day": 1,
            "condition": {
                "text": "Partly cloudy",
                "icon": "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
                "code": 1003
            },
            "wind_mph": 3.8,
            "wind_kph": 6.1,
            "wind_degree": 284,
            "wind_dir": "WNW",
            "pressure_mb": 1015,
            "pressure_in": 30.4,
            "precip_mm": 0,
            "precip_in": 0,
            "humidity": 17,
            "cloud": 1,
            "feelslike_c": 28.2,
            "feelslike_f": 82.8,
            "vis_km": 20,
            "vis_miles": 12
        },
        "forecast": {
            "forecastday": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-09-03",
                    "date_epoch": 1535932800,
                    "day": {
                        "maxtemp_c": 32,
                        "maxtemp_f": 89.6,
                        "mintemp_c": 19.6,
                        "mintemp_f": 67.3,
                        "avgtemp_c": 26.3,
                        "avgtemp_f": 79.4,
                        "maxwind_mph": 4.7,
                        "maxwind_kph": 7.6,
                        "totalprecip_mm": 0,
                        "totalprecip_in": 0,
                        "avgvis_km": 17.5,
                        "avgvis_miles": 10,
                        "avghumidity": 23,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "uv": 7.3
                    },
                    "astro": {
                        "sunrise": "05:39 AM",
                        "sunset": "06:40 PM",
                        "moonrise": "11:26 PM",
                        "moonset": "01:19 PM"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

**below json response for city name and region**

    {
        "id": 2679267,
        "name": "Andidzhan, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.78,
        "lon": 72.34,
        "url": "andidzhan-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2679268,
        "name": "Andijan, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.78,
        "lon": 72.34,
        "url": "andijan-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2681416,
        "name": "Khakan, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.75,
        "lon": 72.37,
        "url": "khakan-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2683610,
        "name": "Stantsiya Andizhan Vtoroy, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.82,
        "lon": 72.37,
        "url": "stantsiya-andizhan-vtoroy-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2679273,
        "name": "Andizhan Vtoroy, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.82,
        "lon": 72.37,
        "url": "andizhan-vtoroy-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2680107,
        "name": "Dal'verzin, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.77,
        "lon": 72.28,
        "url": "dalverzin-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2679050,
        "name": "Agullik, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.73,
        "lon": 72.35,
        "url": "agullik-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2681417,
        "name": "Khaken, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.73,
        "lon": 72.37,
        "url": "khaken-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2680130,
        "name": "Darkhan, Andijon, Uzbekistan",
        "region": "Andijon",
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "lat": 40.73,
        "lon": 72.37,
        "url": "darkhan-andijon-uzbekistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 1315502,
        "name": "Dzhalimbek, Osh, Kyrghyzstan",
        "region": "Osh",
        "country": "Kyrghyzstan",
        "lat": 40.73,
        "lon": 72.32,
        "url": "dzhalimbek-osh-kyrghyzstan"
    }
]
```

Comment: Add please your response from that request.

Comment: @GensaGames,I have added

Comment: I have Answered.

Comment: @GensaGames it is displaying anything I did not understand

Comment: Could you attach R.layout.weather_list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct icon locations url.

```
final String icon = forecastEndingPoint.getCurrent()
      .getCondition().getIcon().replace("//", "");
Picasso.get().load(icon)
      .fit().centerCrop().into(holder.weatherIcon);
```

In case Picasso missing protocol, you might need to add.

```
final String icon = "http:" + forecastEndingPoint.getCurrent()
      .getCondition().getIcon();
Picasso.get().load(icon)
      .fit().centerCrop().into(holder.weatherIcon);
```

Comment: @EdgarSnowden in case of missing protocol. Try to add "http:"

Comment: it is not displaying imageview I think there is some problem xml code but I did not understand what kind of problem

Comment: No, at least one bug with icon for sure. You can try in browser your previous url: "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png" with doesn't work. And correct one is working: "cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png"

Comment: @EdgarSnowden Then something wrong with your xml layout in adapter item.

Comment: what is your suggestion in this case

Comment: @EdgarSnowden You didn't attach this file of XML.

Comment: I did not understand can you tell more briefly

Comment: @EdgarSnowden Could you attach R.layout.weather_list, then bug should be there.